# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host Linux error that works on Windows

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, ssl, rundeck

I have looked at many (too many) similar questions here and tried over and over to solve this one but I can't quite get it to resolve.

I have a java code that connects to a PostGreSQL server on a RHEL 8.2 box to query and return a value.  When I run it on my Windows 10 laptop; it works with no issues.  However, when I run it locally on the Linux box it fails with the dreaded org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host.

The java code is made by a ETL software called Talend; and the code is run on Linux by RunDeck.

To make matters more confusing, I can login on Linux as the postgres user and use the psql interface to connect to the db with the same host, port, db, and user I'm using in Java without error-

`psql -h [server ip] -p 5432 -d my_special_db -U my_db_user`

I have checked the server settings, the pg_hba.conf file, the user permissions, the log files and tried changing all of the above to get some sort of return; all to no avail.

I have added to pg_hba.conf:

```
host    my_special_db        my_db_user        [server ip]/32      md5
host    my_special_db        my_db_user        [server ip with .0 as the last quatraine]/24      md5

host    my_special_db        root        ::1/128      trust
host    all        all        [server ip]/32      trust
```

I have tried multiple connection modifiers like:

```
sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&sslmode=prefer
or
sslmode=prefer
or
sslmode=Require
or
no modifier at all
```

Please advise.

Details:

OS
NAME : Linux RHEL 8.2

VERSION : 4.18.0-372.16.1.el8_6.x86_64

JVM

IMPLEMENTATIONVERSION : 11.0.15+9-LTS

NAME : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

VENDOR : Amazon.com Inc.

VERSION : 11.0.15

PostGreSQL

postgresql11-libs-11.7-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm \

postgresql11-11.7-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm \

postgresql11-server-11.7-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm

Under server > properties > SSL

All Defaults:

SSL Mode: Prefer

Client Cert: [blank]

Client Cert Key: [blank]

Root Cert: [blank]

Cert Rev List: [blank]

SSL compression?: no

```
//////////////////
Under /etc/systemd/system/postgresql-11.service

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL 11 database server
Documentation=https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify

User=postgres
Group=postgres

# Note: avoid inserting whitespace in these Environment= lines, or you may
# break postgresql-setup.

# Location of database directory
Environment=PGDATA=[my data directory path]

# Where to send early-startup messages from the server (before the logging
# options of postgresql.conf take effect)
# This is normally controlled by the global default set by systemd
# StandardOutput=syslog

# Disable OOM kill on the postmaster
OOMScoreAdjust=-1000
Environment=PG_OOM_ADJUST_FILE=/proc/self/oom_score_adj
Environment=PG_OOM_ADJUST_VALUE=0

ExecStartPre=[path to server]/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-check-db-dir ${PGDATA}
ExecStart=[path to server]/pgsql-11/bin/postgres -D ${PGDATA}
#ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
KillSignal=SIGINT
 

# Do not set any timeout value, so that systemd will not kill postmaster
# during crash recovery.
TimeoutSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


[Service]
Environment=PGDATA=[my data directory path]

//////////////////
```

```
//////////////////

Top of the pg_hba.conf file:

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# linux requires a 'local' entry
#local all all md5

local    all             all                     md5

# IPv4 local connections:

host    all        all        0.0.0.0/0      md5

# IPv6 local connections:

host    all        all        ::0/0      md5

# no ssl connection

hostnossl    all        all        0.0.0.0/0      trust

# IPv4 local connections:

hostnossl    all        all        127.0.0.1/32      md5

# IPv6 local connections:

hostnossl    all        all        ::1/128      md5

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.

host    replication        all        127.0.0.1/32      md5
host    replication        all        ::1/128      md5

# This Servers IP and Ranges as Talend doesn't use localhost

host    postgres        postgres        [server ip]/32      md5
host    postgres        all             [server ip with .0 as the last quatraine]/24        md5
host    all             postgres        [server ip]/32      md5
host    all             all             [server ip with .0 as the last quatraine]/24        md5

host    my_special_db        my_db_user        [server ip]/32      md5
host    my_special_db        my_db_user        [server ip with .0 as the last quatraine]/24      md5

host    my_special_db        root        ::1/128      trust
host    all        all        [server ip]/32      trust

//////////////////
```

```
//////////////////

Part of My Java Code:



conn_tDBInput_1 = (java.sql.Connection) globalMap.get("conn_tDBConnection_2");

java.sql.Statement stmt_tDBInput_1 = conn_tDBInput_1.createStatement();

String dbquery_tDBInput_1 = "\n(SELECT ID AS \"id\"\n, ATTRIBUTE AS \"attribute\"\n, DEFINITION AS \"definition\"\n, DESCRIPTION AS \"description\""
        + "\nFROM " + context.SEC_DB_SCHEMA + "." + context.SEC_DB_TABLE
        + "\nWHERE \"description\" = 'my_filter_here'\nLIMIT 1);\n\n";

globalMap.put("tDBInput_1_QUERY", dbquery_tDBInput_1);
java.sql.ResultSet rs_tDBInput_1 = null;

try {
    rs_tDBInput_1 = stmt_tDBInput_1.executeQuery(dbquery_tDBInput_1);
    java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd_tDBInput_1 = rs_tDBInput_1.getMetaData();
    int colQtyInRs_tDBInput_1 = rsmd_tDBInput_1.getColumnCount();

    String tmpContent_tDBInput_1 = null;

    while (rs_tDBInput_1.next()) {
        nb_line_tDBInput_1++;

        if (colQtyInRs_tDBInput_1 < 1) {
            row1.ID = 0;
        } else {

            row1.ID = rs_tDBInput_1.getInt(1);
            if (rs_tDBInput_1.wasNull()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Null value in non-Nullable column");
            }
        }
        if (colQtyInRs_tDBInput_1 < 2) {
            row1.ATTRIBUTE = null;
        } else {

            row1.ATTRIBUTE = routines.system.JDBCUtil.getString(rs_tDBInput_1, 2, false);
        }
        if (colQtyInRs_tDBInput_1 < 3) {
            row1.DEFINITION = null;
        } else {

            row1.DEFINITION = routines.system.JDBCUtil.getString(rs_tDBInput_1, 3, false);
        }
        if (colQtyInRs_tDBInput_1 < 4) {
            row1.DESCRIPTION = null;
        } else {

            row1.DESCRIPTION = routines.system.JDBCUtil.getString(rs_tDBInput_1, 4, false);
        }

        /**
         * [tDBInput_1 begin ] stop
         */

        /**
         * [tDBInput_1 main ] start
         */

        currentComponent = "tDBInput_1";

        tos_count_tDBInput_1++;

        /**
         * [tDBInput_1 main ] stop
         */

        /**
         * [tDBInput_1 process_data_begin ] start
         */

        currentComponent = "tDBInput_1";

        /**
         * [tDBInput_1 process_data_begin ] stop
         */

        /**
         * [tReplicate_1 main ] start
         */

        currentComponent = "tReplicate_1";

        if (execStat) {
            runStat.updateStatOnConnection(iterateId, 1, 1

                    , "row1"

            );
        }

        row5 = new row5Struct();


row5.ID = row1.ID;
row5.ATTRIBUTE = row1.ATTRIBUTE;
row5.DEFINITION = row1.DEFINITION;
row5.DESCRIPTION = row1.DESCRIPTION;

globalMap.put("row5.ATTRIBUTE", row5.ATTRIBUTE);
globalMap.put("row5.DEFINITION", row5.DEFINITION);

// Set Reports DB values

context.DB_HOST = [my_server_ip];
context.DB_NAME = [my_db];
context.DB_PORT = 5432;
// This will have to be changed for each tower will have it's own 'reports' table
context.DB_SCHEMA = "my_schema";
context.DB_TABLE = "my_table";

context.DB_USER = (String)(globalMap.get("row5.ATTRIBUTE"));
context.DB_PWD = (String)(globalMap.get("row5.DEFINITION"));

//------------

    currentComponent="tDBConnection_1";

    
        int tos_count_tDBConnection_1 = 0;
        


    
            String dbProperties_tDBConnection_1 = "sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&sslmode=prefer";
            String url_tDBConnection_1 = "jdbc:postgresql://"+context.DB_HOST+":"+context.DB_PORT+"/"+context.DB_NAME;
            
            if(dbProperties_tDBConnection_1 != null && !"".equals(dbProperties_tDBConnection_1.trim())) {
                url_tDBConnection_1 = url_tDBConnection_1 + "?" + dbProperties_tDBConnection_1;
            }
    String dbUser_tDBConnection_1 = context.DB_USER;
    
//////////////////
```

```
//////////////////

Log entry from the time of trying to connect both locally and remotely-

2022-08-23 15:20:45.452 EDT [67687] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-08-23 15:22:00.719 EDT [67687] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2022-08-23 15:22:00.720 EDT [67687] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-08-23 15:22:00.722 EDT [67687] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 67696) exited with exit code 1
2022-08-23 15:22:00.722 EDT [67691] LOG:  shutting down
2022-08-23 15:22:00.754 EDT [67687] LOG:  database system is shut down
2022-08-23 15:22:00.814 EDT [67739] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-08-23 15:22:00 EDT
2022-08-23 15:22:00.818 EDT [67735] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-08-23 15:52:25.666 EDT [67735] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2022-08-23 15:52:25.668 EDT [67735] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-08-23 15:52:25.669 EDT [67735] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 67745) exited with exit code 1
2022-08-23 15:52:25.669 EDT [67740] LOG:  shutting down
2022-08-23 15:52:25.692 EDT [67735] LOG:  database system is shut down
2022-08-23 15:52:34.188 EDT [79803] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-08-23 15:52:25 EDT
2022-08-23 15:52:34.194 EDT [79801] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

//////////////////////////////////////
```

UPDATE:
Here is a much of the java error message as I can share; given some of the restrictions on what I can post;

```
error message :: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[my_server_ip]", user "my_db_user", database "my_db", SSL off|4
Exception in component tDBConnection_2 (Generic_Talend_Job)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[my_server_ip]", user "my_db_user", database "my_db", SSL off
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:613)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at local_project.generic_talend_job_0_1.Generic_Talend_Job.tDBConnection_2Process(Generic_Talend_Job.java:5752)
    at local_project.generic_talend_job_0_1.Generic_Talend_Job.tSystem_1Process(Generic_Talend_Job.java:5614)
    at local_project.generic_talend_job_0_1.Generic_Talend_Job.tJava_3Process(Generic_Talend_Job.java:5342)
    at local_project.generic_talend_job_0_1.Generic_Talend_Job.tWarn_1Process(Generic_Talend_Job.java:5094)
    at local_project.generic_talend_job_0_1.Generic_Talend_Job.tFileInputDelimited_1Process(Generic_Talend_Job.java:4851)
    at local_project.generic_talend_job_0_1.Generic_Talend_Job.tLibraryLoad_1Process(Generic_Talend_Job.java:4089)
    at local_project.generic_talend_job_0_1.Generic_Talend_Job.tPrejob_1Process(Generic_Talend_Job.java:3856)
    at local_project.generic_talend_job_0_1.Generic_Talend_Job.runJobInTOS(Generic_Talend_Job.java:11916)
    at local_project.generic_talend_job_0_1.Generic_Talend_Job.main(Generic_Talend_Job.java:11245)
    Suppressed: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[my_server_ip]", user "my_db_user", database "my_db", SSL off
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:613)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:161)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222)
        ... 15 more
sec db connection failure, error message :: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[my_server_ip]", user "my_db_user", database "my_db", SSL off
```

Update 2:
Entry from this mornings logs at /data_folder/log after trying again and getting the same error

```
[postgres@my_server_name log]$ vim postgresql-Wed.log
2022-08-24 10:00:17.714 EDT [79801] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2022-08-24 10:00:17.717 EDT [79801] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-08-24 10:00:17.717 EDT [508177] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2022-08-24 10:00:17.717 EDT [508176] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2022-08-24 10:00:17.718 EDT [79801] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 79809) exited with exit code 1
2022-08-24 10:00:17.718 EDT [79804] LOG:  shutting down
2022-08-24 10:00:17.740 EDT [79801] LOG:  database system is shut down
2022-08-24 10:00:35.780 EDT [513920] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-08-24 10:00:17 EDT
2022-08-24 10:00:35.788 EDT [513918] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Update 3:

From the postgresql.conf file:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql, /tmp'  # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)

# - TCP Keepalives -
# see "man 7 tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0        # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0        # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0       # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                    # 0 selects the system default

# - Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
#password_encryption = md5      # md5 or scram-sha-256
#db_user_namespace = off

# GSSAPI using Kerberos
#krb_server_keyfile = ''
#krb_caseins_users = off

# - SSL -

#ssl = off
#ssl_ca_file = ''
#ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
#ssl_crl_file = ''
#ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
#ssl_dh_params_file = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload = off
```

Update 4:

After doing some more searching, I have found that the default for the postgres logging isn't verbose; so this is the verbose part:

```
[636130] [630676b4.9b4e2] [2022-08-24 15:06:28.850 EDT] [] [F0000] [] [] [] [] [] [7] [0]:  LOG:  hostssl record cannot match because SSL is disabled
[636130] [630676b4.9b4e2] [2022-08-24 15:06:28.850 EDT] [] [F0000] [] [] [] [] [] [8] [0]:  HINT:  Set ssl = on in postgresql.conf.
[636130] [630676b4.9b4e2] [2022-08-24 15:06:28.850 EDT] [] [F0000] [] [] [] [] [] [9] [0]:  CONTEXT:  line 103 of configuration file "[data folder path]/pg_hba.conf"
[636132] [630676b4.9b4e4] [2022-08-24 15:06:28.854 EDT] [] [00000] [] [] [] [] [] [1] [0]:  LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-08-24 15:06:18 EDT
[636130] [630676b4.9b4e2] [2022-08-24 15:06:28.859 EDT] [] [00000] [] [] [] [] [] [10] [0]:  LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I have gotten this error even after the following updates-

update to the postgresql.conf file:

```
edit 1
ssl = off
edit 2
ssl = on
edit 3
#ssl = off
```

updated the log level in the postgresql.conf file to

```
log_line_prefix = '[%p] [%c] [%m] [%v] [%e] [%i] [%d] [%u] [%a] [%r] [%l] [%x]:  '  
...
log_statement = 'all'
```

updated the pg_hba.conf file to start with:

```
# Allow any user on the local system to connect to any database with
# any database user name using Unix-domain sockets (the default for local
# connections).
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust

# The same using local loopback TCP/IP connections.
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

# The same as the previous line, but using a separate netmask column
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            IP-ADDRESS      IP-MASK             METHOD
host    all             all             127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255     trust

# The same over IPv6.
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

# The same using a host name (would typically cover both IPv4 and IPv6).
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             localhost               trust
hostssl    all        all        0.0.0.0/0      md5
```

also updated the connection params with-

```
sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

According to postgres this is supposed to stop any and all SSL issues and just let the connections through-

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html

"A non-validating connection is established via a custom SSLSocketFactory class that is provided with the driver. Setting the connection URL parameter sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory will turn off all SSL validation."

Update 5:

Logging settings from postgresql.conf file:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REPORTING AND LOGGING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Where to Log -

log_destination = 'stderr'      # Valid values are combinations of
                    # stderr, csvlog, syslog, and eventlog,
                    # depending on platform.  csvlog
                    # requires logging_collector to be on.

# This is used when logging to stderr:
logging_collector = on          # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
                    # into log files. Required to be on for
                    # csvlogs.
                    # (change requires restart)

# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
log_directory = 'log'           # directory where log files are written,
                    # can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'  # log file name pattern,
                    # can include strftime() escapes
#log_file_mode = 0600           # creation mode for log files,
                    # begin with 0 to use octal notation
log_truncate_on_rotation = on       # If on, an existing log file with the
                    # same name as the new log file will be
                    # truncated rather than appended to.
                    # But such truncation only occurs on
                    # time-driven rotation, not on restarts
                    # or size-driven rotation.  Default is
                    # off, meaning append to existing files
                    # in all cases.
log_rotation_age = 1d           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that time.  0 disables.
log_rotation_size = 0           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that much log output.
                    # 0 disables.

# These are relevant when logging to syslog:
#syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
#syslog_ident = 'postgres'
#syslog_sequence_numbers = on
#syslog_split_messages = on

# This is only relevant when logging to eventlog (win32):
# (change requires restart)
#event_source = 'PostgreSQL'

# - When to Log -

#log_min_messages = warning     # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic

#log_min_error_statement = error    # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic (effectively off)

#log_min_duration_statement = -1    # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
                    # and their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # statements running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds


# - What to Log -

#debug_print_parse = off
#debug_print_rewritten = off
#debug_print_plan = off
#debug_pretty_print = on
#log_checkpoints = off
#log_connections = off
#log_disconnections = off
#log_duration = off
#log_error_verbosity = default      # terse, default, or verbose messages
#log_hostname = off
log_line_prefix = '[%p] [%c] [%m] [%v] [%e] [%i] [%d] [%u] [%a] [%r] [%l] [%x]:  '      # special values:
                    #   %a = application name
                    #   %u = user name
                    #   %d = database name
                    #   %r = remote host and port
                    #   %h = remote host
                    #   %p = process ID
                    #   %t = timestamp without milliseconds
                    #   %m = timestamp with milliseconds
                    #   %n = timestamp with milliseconds (as a Unix epoch)
                    #   %i = command tag
                    #   %e = SQL state
                    #   %c = session ID
                    #   %l = session line number
                    #   %s = session start timestamp
                    #   %v = virtual transaction ID
                    #   %x = transaction ID (0 if none)
                    #   %q = stop here in non-session
                    #        processes
                    #   %% = '%'
                    # e.g. '<%u%%%d> '
#log_lock_waits = off           # log lock waits >= deadlock_timeout
log_statement = 'all'           # none, ddl, mod, all
#log_replication_commands = off
#log_temp_files = -1            # log temporary files equal or larger
                    # than the specified size in kilobytes;
                    # -1 disables, 0 logs all temp files
log_timezone = 'America/New_York'
```

Update 6:

I made edits to the logging part of the config, and now have a lot of output from the log

new logging settings:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REPORTING AND LOGGING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Where to Log -

log_destination = 'stderr'      # Valid values are combinations of
                    # stderr, csvlog, syslog, and eventlog,
                    # depending on platform.  csvlog
                    # requires logging_collector to be on.

# This is used when logging to stderr:
logging_collector = on          # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
                    # into log files. Required to be on for
                    # csvlogs.
                    # (change requires restart)

# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
log_directory = 'log'           # directory where log files are written,
                    # can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'  # log file name pattern,
                    # can include strftime() escapes
#log_file_mode = 0600           # creation mode for log files,
                    # begin with 0 to use octal notation
log_truncate_on_rotation = on       # If on, an existing log file with the
                    # same name as the new log file will be
                    # truncated rather than appended to.
                    # But such truncation only occurs on
                    # time-driven rotation, not on restarts
                    # or size-driven rotation.  Default is
                    # off, meaning append to existing files
                    # in all cases.
log_rotation_age = 1d           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that time.  0 disables.
log_rotation_size = 0           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that much log output.
                    # 0 disables.

# These are relevant when logging to syslog:
#syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
#syslog_ident = 'postgres'
#syslog_sequence_numbers = on
#syslog_split_messages = on

# This is only relevant when logging to eventlog (win32):
# (change requires restart)
#event_source = 'PostgreSQL'

# - When to Log -

log_min_messages = debug5       # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic

log_min_error_statement = debug5    # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic (effectively off)

log_min_duration_statement = 0  # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
                    # and their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # statements running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds


# - What to Log -

#debug_print_parse = off
#debug_print_rewritten = off
#debug_print_plan = off
#debug_pretty_print = on
#log_checkpoints = off
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
#log_duration = off
log_error_verbosity = verbose       # terse, default, or verbose messages
log_hostname = on
log_line_prefix = '[%p] [%c] [%m] [%v] [%e] [%i] [%d] [%u] [%a] [%r] [%l] [%x]:  '      # special values:
                    #   %a = application name
                    #   %u = user name
                    #   %d = database name
                    #   %r = remote host and port
                    #   %h = remote host
                    #   %p = process ID
                    #   %t = timestamp without milliseconds
                    #   %m = timestamp with milliseconds
                    #   %n = timestamp with milliseconds (as a Unix epoch)
                    #   %i = command tag
                    #   %e = SQL state
                    #   %c = session ID
                    #   %l = session line number
                    #   %s = session start timestamp
                    #   %v = virtual transaction ID
                    #   %x = transaction ID (0 if none)
                    #   %q = stop here in non-session
                    #        processes
                    #   %% = '%'
                    # e.g. '<%u%%%d> '
#log_lock_waits = off           # log lock waits >= deadlock_timeout
log_statement = 'all'           # none, ddl, mod, all
#log_replication_commands = off
#log_temp_files = -1            # log temporary files equal or larger
                    # than the specified size in kilobytes;
                    # -1 disables, 0 logs all temp files
log_timezone = 'America/New_York'
```

I couldn't paste the error log here because after making it verbose it was very long- so I made a gist

Last update:

I removed the Gist because the peeps here helped me find my error:

okay, so the issue was 3 things; thing 1, we have a 'properties' file that I thought was set to this server this db; and it wasn't // thing 2, the default logging was set to 'warning' and didn't have enough information so after putting it to debug level 5 (the most data) and on 'all' events; I finally saw a error message that made me realize it was pointed at the wrong db // thing 3, in the many (too many) iterations of my pg_hba.conf file I had added then removed the IP address.
so now it's working, lol
Sometimes you are too close to the tracks to see the train, lol

Comment: 1) There should be more to the error message, can you share it? 2) I am not a JAVA programmer, so this `String dbUser_tDBConnection_1 = context.DB_USER;` is not clear to me. Also I don't see where `context.DB_USER` is set? Also why not include `context.DB_USER` as part of the `url_tDBConnection_1`? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: The rest of the error message will probably have the info you need.

Comment: The entry in `pg_hba.conf` has to contain the *client* address, no the *server* address. This error will cause messages to be written to the PostgreSQL server log. Please show these messages. Please show all the real IP addresses, because the error may well be there.

Comment: Could you test with this config? https://pastebin.com/K85Ea7pt it seems a problem with your "allowed clients" in your postgresql config

Comment: @MegaDrive68k I tried adding those lines but I get the same error message from java; and no error messages in the server log; I posted a update to show more of the error message; that I can share.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The pg_hba.con has the client address; because this is running on the same server; so in this case the host and the client are the same machine.  I hope this clears up any confusion. This is all local and failing.  IF I run this same script from my laptop it works; when it's a remote connection.  I would expect the exact opposite behavior, blocking remote but allowing local. In this case it is just the opposite.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the top of the java code is where those values are being set. as an example only.  This code works on a remote windows machine (my laptop) just fine; but only fails when run on the local sever where the postgresql db resides.

Comment: We need the log entries *that correspond to the error message*.

Comment: 1) The code sample does not show the user value being set. 2) As @LaurenzAlbe says also show the errors as they appear in the Postgres log as your stack seems to be dropping the part of the message that shows what connection is being attempted.

Comment: Do you see `context.DB_USER` anywhere in that?  I don't.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver my apologies, been re-reading what you asked for and totally missed that.  I thought you were asking for the context.DB_NAME; it's been a long week, I'll add those to my example.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe even after I turned on the more verbose logging; the logs don't have entries for that error; it's like it never gets that far, if that makes sense.  I only have log entries for when the connection happens.  postgresql/pgdata-11/log/postgresql-Wed.log doesn't have any entries for the failed attempts from today and neither do the other prev days.  Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense: this error *always* produces log entries, unless you set `log_min_messages` to `FATAL` or higher. Check how logging is configured. Since this is Windows, it might go to the event log.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe to clarify, the errors are not happening on windows, they are happening on linux, but I will double check the logging settings and put in another update, thanks.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I updated the logging settings and couldn't post the log here but created a gist to house it.

Comment: If that is indeed the log from the time of the problem, then (since you have set `log_min_messages` to debugging) the conclusion must be that the connection attempt that caused the error in the title of your question must have been to a different PostgreSQL server.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  so you and Adrian Klaver helped me see past the end of my own nose, okay, so the issue was 3 things; thing 1, we have a 'properties' file that I thought was set to this server this db; and it wasn't // thing 2, the default logging was set to 'warning' and didn't have enough information so after putting it to debug level 5 (the most data) and on 'all' events; I finally saw a error message that made me realize it was pointed at the wrong db // thing 3, in the many (too many) iterations of my pg_hba.conf file I had added then removed the IP address. // now pointed and logged. lol

Comment: @AdrianKlaver if you and Laurenz want to split the answer; give me a couple to vote on.

Comment: Thanks everyone, sometimes if you're too close to the tracks you can't see the train

Comment: Remember to put your solution as an answer and mark it as valid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the Gist because the peeps here helped me find my error:

okay, so the issue was 3 things; thing 1, we have a 'properties' file that I thought was set to this server this db; and it wasn't // thing 2, the default logging was set to 'warning' and didn't have enough information so after putting it to debug level 5 (the most data) and on 'all' events; I finally saw a error message that made me realize it was pointed at the wrong db // thing 3, in the many (too many) iterations of my pg_hba.conf file I had added then removed the IP address. so now it's working, lol Sometimes you are too close to the tracks to see the train, lol